# El espacio actúa como carácter nulo

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

int aux;
char name[20];
char hello[8] = "Hello, "; 

printf("Introduce your name: ");
scanf("%s", name); 
printf("%s %s", hello, name); 
printf("\nYour name starts with %c\n", name[0]); 

aux = strlen(name);
printf("The size of the char is %d", aux);

return 0;

}
```

Al correr este programa, si introduces un único nombre funciona bien, pero en cuanto le pones un nombre compuesto (o en general introduces un espacio por pantalla), el programa solo te muestra hasta el espacio. Estoy usando el compilador Dev C++. De hecho con "strlen" te dice que el nuevo tamaño de la cadena es la cantidad de caracteres que hayas puesto antes del espacio. ¿ALguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 8):

> ¿ALguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

Pasa lo que tiene que pasar. `scanf` deja de leer una cadena de caracteres cuando se encuentra con un separador. ¿Y qué es un separador? Algunos ejemplos:

- Alcanzar el final del buffer de entrada `EOF`
- Salto de línea: `'\n'`, `'\r'`
- Tabulador: `'\t'`
- Espacio: `' '`

Así pues, en virtud del 4º punto, `scanf` deja de leer cuando se encuentra con un espacio. Que es justo lo que te está sucendiendo.

¿Soluciones? Haberlas las hay... puedes usar [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

```
size_t max_length = sizeof(name); // max_length = 20
getline(&name, &max_length, stdin);
```

A diferencia de `scanf`, `getline` leerá todos los caracteres hasta llegar a un salto de línea o al final del buffer de entrada.